# Calling method from MVC controller hangs due to async await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've been playing around with creating a REST wrapper based on  https://github.com/JeffGos/urbanairsharp.

```
public LoginResponse Login()
    {
        return SendRequest(new LoginRequest(new Model.Login()));
    }

private static TResponse SendRequest<TResponse>(BaseRequest<TResponse> request) where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
    {
        try
        {
            var requestTask = request.ExecuteAsync();

            return requestTask.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log.Error(request.GetType().FullName, e);

            return new TResponse()
            {
                Error = e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : e.Message,
                Ok = false
            };
        }
    }
```

I am able to call the Login method absolutely fine from a console app but if I call it from an MVC controller, it steps through the code fine but never passes the line

```
var requestTask = request.ExecuteAsync();
```

I have read around the subject but dont quite understand how I can use these methods from a web app? The Login() method is not async so I dont see why it would fail from my MVC action (also non-async)?

Thanks

Comment: I believe [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) may hold your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
var requestTask = request.ExecuteAsync();
return requestTask.Result;
```

Is causing your code to deadlock. You're blocking an async method synchronously with the call to `Task.Result` That's why [*you shouldn't block on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead, you need to asynchronously wait on ir with `await`. This will effectively make your call chain become async as well:

```
public Task<LoginResponse> LoginAsync()
{
    return SendRequestAsync(new LoginRequest(new Model.Login()));
}

private static async Task<TResponse> SendRequestAsync<TResponse>(BaseRequest<TResponse> request) where TResponse : BaseResponse, new()
{
    try
    {
        return await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log.Error(request.GetType().FullName, e);

        return new TResponse()
        {
            Error = e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : e.Message,
            Ok = false
        };
    }
}
```

In case you can't change your call chain to become asynchronous, use a synchronous API instead.

Comment: ok that did the trick and I think I am understand a little more. I did read that article you mention previously but I don't quite understand why this is blocking the request. What is the point of doing it the way I previously had it?

Comment: Also, is it possible to call the LoginAsync method from a synchronous legacy VB.NET WebForm as NON async call? I tried just creating an instance of my class and calling it without Await and it seems to deadlock as before? I dont really want to start adding async everywhere to a legacy application...

Comment: @Raj No, I would definitely recommend agains't that. Async and sync methods usually have different code execution paths, and need to be "duplicated". You shouldn't do [*"sync over async"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) nor [*"async over sync"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: @Raj Regarding your first comment, there is no advantage to executing an async method synchronously. That'll mainly lead you to cases of deadlock like you've just experienced.